# Does the Android NDK work in Windows 7?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have been working on learning the Android NDK the past few days, but I was just looking at their website and it says the only supported Windows operating systems are Vista and XP. Does anyone know if this is true? I figured they may have just not updated it. Thanks

EDIT:

[Link to NDK System Requirements](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/overview.html#reqs%5C)

Comment: if it is working on Vista it is likely that it will work on Windows 7. Have you tried installing it. You can always test it first in a VM.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm getting cygwin now, but just wondering here, does that mean before windows 7 i didn't need to use cygwin..?

Comment: It doesn't need Cygwin. NDK works without Cygwin on Windows starting with Revision 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does work on Windows 7.
Look at this tutorial : 
[Android NDK on Windows 7](http://psrdotcom.blogspot.fr/2011/12/android-ndk-jni-windows-xp7-with-3264.html)