# Does Android NDK work on Windows 8?

Tags: android, windows-8, android-ndk

According to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158445/does-the-android-ndk-work-in-windows-7), Android NDK works on Windows 7. Before I go down this path, does anyone know if [these same steps](http://psrdotcom.blogspot.fr/2011/12/android-ndk-jni-windows-xp7-with-3264.html) will work under Windows 8? Or is it time to find a linux box to compile my native libs on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does work in windows 8.

Comment: +1 for now -- trust but verify. I'll mark as answered when this bad boy is up and running.